# Split Hive table on subtables by field value

Tags: hive, batch-processing, hiveql

I have a Hive table `foo`. There are several fields in this table. One of them is `some_id`. Number of unique values in this fields in range 5,000-10,000. For each value (in example it `10385`) I need to perform `CTAS` queries like

```
CREATE TABLE bar_10385 AS 
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE some_id=10385 AND other_id=10385;
```

What is the best way to perform this bunch of queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can store all these tables in the single partitioned one. This approach will allow you to load all the data in single query. Query performance will not be compromised.

```
Create table T (
... --columns here
) 
partitioned by (id int); --new calculated partition key
```

Load data using one query, it will read source table only once:

```
insert overwrite table T partition(id)
select ..., --columns
       case when some_id=10385 AND other_id=10385 then 10385 
            when some_id=10386 AND other_id=10386 then 10386
            ...
            --and so on
            else 0 --default partition for records not attributed
        end as id --partition column
   from foo
  where some_id in (10385,10386) AND other_id in (10385,10386) --filter
```

Then you can use this table in queries specifying partition:

```
select from T where id = 10385; --you can create a view named bar_10385, it will act the same as your table. Partition pruning works fast
```